# Could I get some help on changing auth tokens mid test?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to run a test that processes an order, mid way through the test I need to approve the order via a back office application and then continue with the test.

The issue I'm having is that when I login to the back office application and attempt to approve the order it fails as it's still using the old auth token.

How can I store the new auth token ?